# How to vertically align data in the center of a table cell in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table with two rows and two cells in each row.
Cell 1 in each row has an image placeholder.
Cell 2 in each row has some text (different in every cell).

When I load it to the server it shows up like the image (cell 1) is aligned to the top and the text (cell2) is lower than the lower edge of an image.

I've tried `v-align` property for the table, vertical-align CSS property, cell padding, smaller font, smaller image etc.

Always get the same result.

Comment: For starters you should't use tables for that.

Comment: I assume you meant "shouldn't"?

Comment: ouch, you *really* shouldn't be using tables for this. that being said: the `td`'s have `vertical-align:baseline` - if you change that to `middle` it *should* work.

Comment: @ptriek OMG I suck bug time :P Too late cannot edit it anymore :) Just use my answer for reference as to what I mean :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make that thing into `li`'s.

HTML:

```
<ul class="usps">
  <li>Denver’s Only LOCAL Ad Posting Service.</li>
  <li>Your first week of ad posting is FREE!!!  We are that confident of our ability to post LIVE Ads for your firm!!!</li>
  <li>etc</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.usps { list-style-image: url('checkbox.png'); }
```

For you question:

That's because you have set the `vertical-align` wrong (`baseline`). This alignes the stuff to the baseline of the parent element.

Answer (score 4):

`vertical-align:middle;` in CSS

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you typed the properties in correctly? Using Chrome's Dev Tools and editing the CSS, this worked for me:

```
.content td { vertical-align: middle; }
```

@PeeHaa is right that you should not be using `<table>` for this since it's not tabular data. The most semantically correct choice here would be `<ul>` with:

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `vertical-align:baseline` from your `tr` definition. Then, to keep your spacing, add `height: 65px;`

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
vertical-align: baseline;
```

in your style.css, line 15. This is preventing it from looking how you want it to.